# JavaScript - кросдоменные HTTP запросы

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

В браузере выполняю запрос

```
    var xhr = ( window.XMLHttpRequest && "withCredentials" in (new XMLHttpRequest) ) ?
            new XMLHttpRequest : window.XDomainRequest ? new XDomainRequest : null;

    if ( xhr ) {
        xhr.open( "GET", "https://ya.ru", false );
        xhr.onload = function() {
            alert( this.responseText );
        }
        xhr.onerror = function() {
            alert( "Не удалось сделать запрос" );
        }
        xhr.send( null );
    } else {
        alert( "Не поддерживается" );
    }
```

Приходит ошибка

```
  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

А как получить ответ от сервера, не меняя ничего на этом сервере?

Comment: Никак. В этом смысл cors

Comment: Почему тогда этого запрета нет, например, в Java, PHP ?

Comment: Потому что они не браузер и у них нет пользовательских кук.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: @DcoartB браузер сделан для обычных пользователей и кроссдоменный запрос вернет информацию вместе со всеми потрохами т.к. отправляет еще и куки. Я думаю вам бы не хотелось, что бы сайт сделал xhr и вытащил все ваши данные для авторизации и похитил аккаунты подобно XSS. Поэтому браузер защищает пользователя от подобного поведения сайта.